# Outlook Web Add-In error 'There were deployment errors. Continue?'

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Currently I'm working on an Outlook Add-In using Visual Studio 2022 with React (TypeScript). When starting the application a message box appears containing following message:

> There were deployment errors. Continue?

The output of the build console doesn't help at all because it only says that an error has occurred but without any further information.
[image: Output build console]

Is there any way to get more error details or does anyone know how to fix this?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
<Id>0ca51293-705c-45d5-975c-e59909dab3ea</Id>
<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
<ProviderName>Company</ProviderName>
<DefaultLocale>de-DE</DefaultLocale>
<DisplayName DefaultValue="OutlookAddInWeb" />
<Description DefaultValue="OutlookAddInWeb Description" />
<IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button64x64.png" />
<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button80x80.png" />
<SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.somesite.com/" />
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:44488</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
</Hosts>
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
        <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
<FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
        <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/" />
        </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
</FormSettings>
<Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
<Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
<DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
        <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
                <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
            </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                                <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                                        <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                                    <Label resid="ActionButton.Label" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="ActionButton.Label" />
                                        <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button16x16.png" />
                <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button32x32.png" />
                <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button80x80.png" />
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/commands.html" />
                <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/" />
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Outlook Add-in" />
                <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
                <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action" />
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties." />
                <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked." />
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
        <WebApplicationInfo>
            <Id>1d32bd7d-70ab-42b5-b11a-8e73a6b8ab4a</Id>
            <Resource>api://localhost:44488/1d32bd7d-70ab-42b5-b11a-8e73a6b8ab4a</Resource>
            <Scopes>
                <Scope>openid</Scope>
                <Scope>profile</Scope>
            </Scopes>
        </WebApplicationInfo>
    </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Can you share your manifest file?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have added the contents of the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest to validate your manifest file. There are issues with your manifest file.

Comment: The validation only fails because of the placeholder "~remoteAppUrl" but this gets replaced by Visual Studio. Replacing this placeholder results in a valid manifest, so there aren't any issues with the file.

Comment: @ErikT. could you try using the Yeoman generator tool for your project (if it fits your use case) and let us know if this resolves the issue?

You can find the link to the documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/yeoman-generator-overview

Comment: Even with a valid Manifest that passes the validation, the deployment error still pops up in VS2022 17.8.6 though the app does seem to run in Outlook.